# Undefined variable error when reference yii controller defined public variable in view

Tags: php, yii

In yii framework helloworld, I defined a variable in controller class

```
class MessageController extends Controller
{
        public $time = 'ok';
```

Supposely I could reference the variable `$time` in relevant view class using `$this->$time`.

But I am seeing variable undefined error.

Anything I might be missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo... I guess you mean $this->time (without the $ in time).